# Edittext help - onKeyListener doesn't work

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I have a simple edittext that I've added to my layout. I added a simple OnKeyListener as follows in the onCreate method:

```
final EditText simpleEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
simpleEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
@Override
public boolean onKey(View arg0, int arg1, KeyEvent arg2) {
    System.out.println("HELLO");
    return false;
}
});
```

When the application starts, everything works correctly. For every key pressed, HELLO is printed twice - once for DOWN action and once for UP action.

Now when I click on the edittext with my mouse, the edittext no longer runs the code in my onKey method. What am I doing wrong? I'd still like to receive key events after the user has clicked in the edittext. I don't care about the mouse click, I'm only using that to reposition the cursor. After the cursor is repositioned, the key events are no longer registered.

Please see the attached image to see more information.

Thanks
Zamil

https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2DP7.jpg

Answer (score 1):

[As per android API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html), onKey works only **for the physical key that was pressed**. You may need to consider OnClickListener for mouse clicks. Here is API [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

Comment: I'd still like to receive key events after the user has clicked in the edittext. I don't care about the mouse click, I'm only using that to reposition the cursor. After the cursor is repositioned, the key events are no longer registered.

Answer (score 0):

Click events are not key events. You won't (and shouldn't) receive onKey events for anything except key events.

Comment: I'd still like to receive key events after the user has clicked in the edittext. I don't care about the mouse click, I'm only using that to reposition the cursor. After the cursor is repositioned, the key events are no longer registered.